Can you fill this staircase with 1's and 2's?
Can you fill the cells in the staircase below with 1's and 2's so that the row-sums and column-sums are all distinct? If yes, how many distinct fillings are there?


For those who like the challenge: How about when the staircase has height and width n? (The above question is for n=6.)

Example: there are exactly two ways for n=2:

In the left picture, the two row-sums are 1 and 4, and the two column-sums are 3 and 2, which are all distinct as required.

Source: I found this question on math.SE here and it felt appropriate for the audience here. It does have an answer there, so please don't open this link if you don't want to see the answer.

The number of solutions is

 2^(n/2) if n even and 0 otherwise.

Proof:

 There are 2n columns and rows in total. As the smallest and largest sums possible are 1 and 2n for the sums to be all distinct they must have values 1,2,3,...,2n. Now, 2n and 2n-1 can only be formed in the first row or column. As their tips being a one element column or row they must be distinct, and all the other elements must be 2s.


 The remaining rows and columns must take the remaining values, which are 3,4,...,2n-2. Removing the first row and first column reduces each of these sums by 2, and hence leaves us with the original problem at size n reduced by 2.


 Repeating the procedure floor(n/2) times leaves us with n=1 or n=0. The former is unsolvable because it gives rise to a length 1 row and a length 1 column with identical value. The latter has one solution, namely the empty set.


 At each of the above reduction steps we can place the single 1 either in the first column or the first row. These two choices are independent for each of the floor(n/2) steps.

